# Handle 404 exception in Spring

Tags: spring

I'm trying to catch 404 error on my Spring boot + Hibernate Server when Im going to some page that doesn't exist (for example http://localhost:8080/tes (http://localhost:8080/test is working)). I've created @ControllerAdvice class but it can't catch 404 exception (other works just fine). What is problem?

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = NullPointerException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleNullPointerException(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("A null pointer exception ocurred " + e);
        return "nullpointerExceptionPage";
    }


    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleAllException(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("A unknow Exception Ocurred: " + e);
        return "unknowExceptionPage";
    }


    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ResponseBody
    public String handleResourceNotFoundException() {
        return "notFoundJSPPage";
   }
```

Comment: I think that we should defined 404 page in web.xml

Comment: have you registered that controlleradvice as bean by component scan or ...?